# Using findbugs-slf4j plugin with maven

Tags: java, java-8, slf4j, findbugs

I am trying `findbugs-slf4j` plugin with maven. As mentioned in their [documentation](http://kengotoda.github.io/findbugs-slf4j/) I have added the below in my `pom.xml

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>jp.skypencil.findbugs.slf4j</groupId>
              <artifactId>bug-pattern</artifactId>
              <version>1.2.4</version>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

To test this I added a log like below in my code

```
logger.error("Could not send inventory data to collector. Exception: {}", e); // where e is an instance of Exception
```

But on compiling the project and then executing `mvn findbugs:findbugs` and then `mvn findbugs:gui` I am not seeing any bugs related to `SLF4J_PLACE_HOLDER_MISMATCH`.

**EDIT**
As suggested in one of the answer I changes my plugin dependency to

```
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0-RC7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>jp.skypencil.findbugs.slf4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>bug-pattern</artifactId>
                            <version>1.2.4</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

But on running `mvn spotbugs:spotbugs` it is throwing me the below error

```
No plugin found for prefix 'spotbugs' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/dmanna/.m2/repository), central (http://artifactory.srk.local:8080/plugins-release), snapshots (http://artifactory.srk.local:8080/plugins-snapshot)]
```

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Wrong plugin and task

It looks like the documentation on [this page](http://kengotoda.github.io/findbugs-slf4j/) is outdated and differs from the [README](https://github.com/KengoTODA/findbugs-slf4j#how-to-use-with-maven) which apparently is the correct one.
You should include the plugin using the following artifact:

```
<groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
<artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0-RC7</version>
```

The correct maven task to use with this one is **`spotbugs:spotbugs`** instead of `findbugs:findbugs`.

#### Old answer

Let's see what the `SLF4J_PLACE_HOLDER_MISMATCH` rule checks for...

> This pattern checks how placeholder is used. Alert if count of placeholder does not match to count of parameter.

You have **one** placeholder and **one** parameter, hence there is no violation of `SLF4J_PLACE_HOLDER_MISMATCH` as per the [documentation](https://github.com/KengoTODA/findbugs-slf4j#slf4j_place_holder_mismatch), that's why you don't see any bugs reported. **Keep in mind that this is not true for Throwable instances as they do not need a placeholder.**

Try to use the test cases from the documentation to see if the plugin works correctly in your setup.

Comment: As per the documentation `logger.error("{}, {}", "Hello", new RuntimeException());` this is invalid as `Throwable instance does not need placeholder`

Comment: @tuk You haven't stated that what you pass as a parameter is an instance of  `Throwable`, please include that info as apparently it's crucial.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: @tuk check the edited answer. It looks like you've been using an obsolete doc.

Comment: I have made the changes in my pom.xml as you said. But that is giving me some other. Please check the edit in my quesiton.

Comment: @maciekjanusz I've fixed [that page](http://kengotoda.github.io/findbugs-slf4j/), thanks for your pointing out!

Answer (score 2):

Move your `<plugin>...</plugin>` from `<reporting><plugins>` to `<build><plugins>`. The plugin inside of `<reporting>` will triggered only when you kick `site` goal.

- https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Reporting

Comment: That's it, it works for me under the build set. Also, thanks for updating the doc!

Comment: I am trying to run in a multi-module project but it is giving me the error on doing `mvn spotbugs:gui` -  `Failed to execute goal com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:3.1.0-RC7:gui (default-cli) on project reg-common: Execution default-cli of goal com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:3.1.0-RC7:gui failed: java doesn't support the nested "getThresholdParameter" element.: The <java> type doesn't support the nested "getThresholdParameter" element. -> [Help 1]`

Comment: gui goal still has opened issue. https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-maven-plugin/issues/10

Comment: If 3.1.0-RC8 cannot solve your problem, issue a bug report with a minimum protject to reproduce.